# Creating report in asp.net with many web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with report creation.
I have an asp.net web application with GridView that contains results.
For each result I can press link that redirect me to another page with GridView with more details.
I want to download all the pages and populate the Gridviews in Html format without redirected to the webpages.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired format for saving?

Comment: Why download the pages? You refer to `GridView`s, which means that probably they are on the same application. Just move the details `GridView` to the results page. You could add one details `GridView` per row, but maybe that's not a good idea for page speed and server load, as it will also get unwanted/unnecessary details.

Comment: Hi Alexander - I want to save it as Html Pages.

Comment: Hi Alex Filpovici - I don't know how to move the result to other page without open them.